# Acess External SD card with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm developing a native apk for android with NDK 5.

My question is, how do I access to write and read from external SD card from native code?

PS: Testing under Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
fopen("/sdcard/filename.ext", "r+")
```

?

Comment: Actually, I already solved, this is the right answer, I was confused cause in the folder structure there's not a "/sdcard/" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210154/android-sd-card-characteristics-on-samsung-galaxy) answer, things are little bit complicated for Galaxy Tab