# Android File directories

Tags: java, android, file, url, directory

I have a code of getting the External Storage Directory of my android device: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, it returns `/mnt/sdcard/`
But when I use the **files and folders viewer** of my android device (samsung galaxy tab), the external storage direcory there is named `external_sd` **which is under the 
root folder**. So to access the sd card, I have to go `/Root/external_sd`

Strange, how to I fix this? so that when I run the code `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, it will return the `/Root/external_sd` or fix my directory so when
I have to access my sd card using the files and folder viewer, I will access `/mnt/sdcard`..

Comment: See the answer to this question, I think this will solve your query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210154/android-sd-card-characteristics-on-samsung-galaxy