# Is it possible to get Android SD card location on SAMSUNG Tablet / Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin

I have looked over many posts on getting SD card locations, and most that mention using `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`,   `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` always returns internal storage for my on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A / Android 11 (`/storage/emulated/0`)

I did see a comment that said to use `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")`, which returns `/storage/sdcard:/storage/usb1:/storage/usb2`, but trying to open a file (I have put there) just returns a `not found` error (ie `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/external_sd/Music/test/testfile.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.

Also tried `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED).getPath()` and this returns `/storage/emulated/0/mounted` and this does not work either

I have the following permissions..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERMISSIONS_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and at startup I call

```
 private fun verifyStoragePermissions(activity: Activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    val permission =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            
        )
    }
}
```

Finally, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210154/android-sd-card-characteristics-on-samsung-galaxy.), I hardwired `/sdcard/external_sd` and this did not work either (ie I try to open a file I know is there, and also using the following to list contents..

```
File(testFolder).walk().forEach {
            println(it)
        }
```

I have other application that writes to it, so there must be some way to do it (I only want to read  existing files).

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: "I have the following permissions" -- the latter two are not actual permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
File[] dirs = getExternalFilesDirs("");
for (File currD :
        dirs) {
    if (currD.getAbsolutePath().equals(getExternalFilesDir("").getAbsolutePath())) {
        // Here is internal storage path
    } else {
        // Here is SD path
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close enough. First try I dismissed, as it never went into the else. But looking in dirs I could see two paths, and one of them was the storage card (/storage/3BDD-1A1D)

Comment: Thanks i spent 2 days looking for a path to sd-card in android 12.
And only here I found the correct answer