# How to start the Files app to display my folder through button onClick

Tags: android, button, internal-storage

Can a button in app redirecting to phone internal folder? I need to make a button that not just retrieving the data from the phone storage but literally switch the app to the phone folder.

For the button:

```
androidx.appcomat.widget.AppCompatButton log = findViewById(R.id.log);
log.setOnClickListener(view -> {
//code to switch the app to phone folder
});
```

The path that needed to be opened is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/`

Is there any reference about this? I tried to search the webs but I can only find about how to retrieve the data from folder.

//Edit
If I click the button, the app switch to the folder so it would be look like this:
[image: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/]

Comment: Check my answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590865/is-it-possible-to-get-android-sd-card-location-on-samsung-tablet-android-11/72590912#72590912 it provides access to both /android/data/ directories of your app in both internal storage and SD storage

Comment: @blackapps the path exists and I could open the path even save pdf from the app

Comment: @blackapps that's what I've been asking. How to switch the app by using button onClick

Comment: @DanBaruch do I type the storage path at "//Here is internal storage path"? Does it could switch the app to open the storage?

Comment: @blackapps if the button clicked, the screen will change to the folder. Then we can see the files inside the folder.

Comment: @blackapps I've edit my question and post a pic of what should be seen.

Comment: @blackapps the pic is from my phone storage which the path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/. That pic is what must be shown when the button of my app clicked. Pdf that shown in it was saved from my app. I want a button to switch the app to the folder app.

Comment: @blackapps I need to switch the app.Not just using List/RecyclerView

Comment: @blackapps the app name is "Files". Every phone should have the Files/File manager app.

Comment: Running on Android 11 and above won't allow you do to that as Android is preventing other apps from accessing your app's internal files. You can check if there's a way for you to send the data to the file browsing app and show it to the user or implement your own viewer

Comment: "Every phone should have the Files/File manager app" -- you are very, very mistaken. First, there is no requirement for a device manufacturer to ship such an app. Second, there is no requirement for a device manufacturer to ship a *specific* version of such an app. Third, there is nothing in the Android SDK for opening a file manager on a particular directory, in part because there is no requirement for a device to have one. Fourth, even if the *device* has one, the *user* might not be able to access it due to device or account policies.

Comment: @CommonsWare which Android phone manufacturer didn't include files/file manager as default application? I've tried Samsung, Oppo, Vivo, Xiaomi, Realmi, Infinix and Honor. All of them have files/file manager as default application so I didn't know any other phones that doesn't have files/file manager as their default application.

Comment: "which Android phone manufacturer didn't include files/file manager as default application?" -- there are **tens of thousands** of device models, of varying ages. You have tested far fewer than that. Of note, you appear to have not tested devices from Google, Huawei, Moto/Levono, and Unihertz, to name a few. And, again, there is nothing in the Android SDK for what you seek, and users may not have access to any such app even if it happens to be installed.